# Decode special character in php

Tags: php, regex, special-characters

Please tell me. How to decode `&#x98EF;` in php.

I am getting this value when I am generating XML.

I have used already `html_entity_Decode()` , `htmlspecialchars_decode()` but not able to decode it.

It is not the chinese character. on my website it is  Décor Items . and I am getting it as D 飯 cor Items

Does any one know how to decode it.

Comment: I think it's Kanji/Chinese Character, so probably using correct character encoding will solved it.

Comment: what will it be and how to use it.Please let me know

Comment: In this case, what you want to do? just echoing or something else?

Comment: @Bhuvnesh Gupta Show your xml

Comment: `html_entity_decode` works as expected. See http://ideone.com/eCoyBw

Comment: @SomyA I just want to echo in my xml file.Please see my update question

Comment: @falsetru this is not working

Comment: make sure header encoding correct : header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Comment: [`&#x98ef;`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/98ef/index.htm) is `飯`.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything to decode. It's the HTML value for 飯. Just like &nbsp;

```
<?php
echo "&#x98EF;";
```

Comment: no it is not the chineses character. on my website it is  Décor Items . and I am getting it as D &#x98EF; cor Items

Comment: make sure header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Comment: Do i need to use it as a php function ?? 
I used it as <?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?> at top of file but it did not work.

Comment: Is your XML using the correct encoding? `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`